# Query which orders users by last message sent in Django Private Chat

Tags: django, django-queryset

I want to create a queryset which retrieve users efficiently ordered by the create date of the last Message they sent OR received (like most of the chat interfaces do). I am using Django Private Chat, which uses [this simple model](https://github.com/Bearle/django-private-chat/blob/dev/django_private_chat/models.py) for messages.

I simply don't know how writing the `order_by` statement considering the previous model. Maybe annotate, Subquery or other query expressions would be convenient in this case.

```
users = User.objects.filter(
    username__icontains=user,
    id__in=request.user.followers
).order_by( ????? )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do this using `annotate` and something like;

```
from django.db.models import Max

users = User.objects.filter(
    username__icontains=user,
    id__in=request.user.followers
).annotate(
    last_message=Max('messages_created')
).order_by('-last_message')
```

The `Max` function takes the related name from the `Message` model, found [here](https://github.com/Bearle/django-private-chat/blob/dev/django_private_chat/models.py#L22), then the `created` timestamp of that model.